# How to associate a point with a file on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, csv, import

Trying to plot CTD data from an oceanography cruise on Google Earth Engine so that it can be compared to MODIS ocean color.

The trouble is, each measurement is a separate CSV, and I would like to associate the CSV with each point where the measurement took place.

I was thinking of making points (213 of them), each named after the file (ex: `var poi = ee.Geometry.Point(long, lat), {name: 'measurement_1.csv'};` and then calling the files—is there anyone who has done this?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because Earth Engine does not permit specifying asset IDs using computed values (such as property values from features).

You will need to upload all the measurement data as a single asset — or, if it is more convenient or necessary for size, several assets, but your script must name all of them explicitly (or at least client-side). You could add an `original_filename` column to the CSV if it makes sense for your data organization.